# create a color coded image from 2D array of angles

Tags: python

i am trying to write some code in python relating angles to a certain colors. basically i have a 2d array full of angles where i looped through other arrays to perform calculations to arrive at ha_deg for each pixel

```
ha_array[i,j] = ha_deg
```

and i want to turn this into an image with color gradients.  so if 0 is red, 180 is green and 360 is blue, i will be able to go pixel by pixel to assign a color to each angle. sorry this is kind of an open ended question, I'm just not really sure how to proceed and could use some guidance! thank you!

Comment: In RGB space, there are an infinite number of paths you can take to get from red `(255, 0, 0)` to green `(0, 255, 0)`, to blue `(0, 0, 255)`.  Do you have a specific path in mind, or is any one good enough?

Comment: Use `pylab`. Sepcifically, you are looking for the `imshow` or `contour` functions. its as simple as calling `imshow(ha_array);` etc. Documentation here: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contourf_demo.html

Comment: There is another tutorial for making custom colormaps : http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Show_colormaps. But for practically all purposes, the colormaps already available are generally sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do this.  Below is a general function for generating linear RGB color gradients between two RGB values.  By combining color gradients of the appropriate lengths from red to green and from green to blue, one can make a list of RGB color values that can serve as a map between your angle values and the desired colors:

```
def generateColorGradient(RGB1, RGB2, n, includeEnd=False):
    dRGB = [float(x2-x1)/(n-1) for x1, x2 in zip(RGB1, RGB2)]
    gradient = [tuple([int(x+k*dx) for x, dx in zip(RGB1, dRGB)]) for k in range(n-1+includeEnd)]
    return gradient

gradient1 = generateColorGradient((255, 0, 0), (0, 255, 0), 181, includeEnd=False)
gradient2 = generateColorGradient((0, 255, 0), (0, 0, 255), 181, includeEnd=True)

gradient = numpy.array(gradient1 + gradient2)

#If `ha_array` is a numpy array, you can simply do this to convert all angles to RGB values:

color_array = gradient[ha_array]

#Then if you're using PIL to make images:

image = Image.fromarray(numpy.uint8(color_array))
```

Comment: ha_array is a numpy array, but when i try that bit of code it gives me an error message IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type. can you explain what this means? and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you remember to make the `gradient` list a numpy array too?  With the `gradient = numpy.array(gradient)` step?

Comment: I've simplified my answer so it's easier to run - try it again and let me know how it goes.